# Using USB flash as a "second computer" with Ubuntu

Tags: usb, flash

From what I understand, you can install Ubuntu on a flash drive and run it as a try version. But after searching a while, I found that files and work do not save, so they are lost. I heard that Ubuntu is the best for development work, but I also like playing video games and the majority I enjoy don't have Linux versions. I also don't have the money to buy a second computer and I don't want to use VirtualBox because I heard it might be dangerous for data and reduces performance.

My idea would be to use the flash drive memory to keep apps and documents I use on the Ubuntu try version and then I can have them again when I use the try version. As I see it, this would be like using my computer's brains (processor, RAM memory, motherboard, etc) to run another computer (without brains, saved on a big flash drive, like 32GB or 64GB).

Is it possible? Had anyone tried this?

Comment: Worth trying and you are not risking anything as you'll be using external Drive. I had Ubuntu installed on external HDD and it worked perfectly for me...

Comment: You can also install Ubuntu in a dual-boot setup with Windows where you choose which operating systems to boot when switching on your computer.